# How to make a route parameter optional in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How to make a route parameter optional in Azure Function

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post",
        Route = "ResolveKey/{key}/{resolver}")]
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    TraceWriter log,
    string key,
    string resolver = "default")
```

In the above code I tried to make resolver parameter optional by setting a default value  `string resolver = "default"` . The code compiles and runs fine, but the URL always wants resolver parameter to be present, otherwise I get 404.

I want to make the resolver parameter optional in the above code. Is there any way?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can express that a parameter is optional in the route template itself.

For the route above, you can just change your template to the following:

```
ResolveKey/{key}/{resolver?}
```

You can find more information about optional routes and default values [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional-uri-parameters-and-default-values)

Comment: For those who are looking to match a full path in the resolver, Azure function will url encode the `{resolver?}` match by default. You will need to include an app setting to work around this, `AZURE_FUNCTION_PROXY_BACKEND_URL_DECODE_SLASHES : true`. (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2249#issuecomment-391167871)

Answer (score 3):

Azure Functions now support regular expressions. You can change your routing template to

```
ResolveKey/{key}/{*resolver}
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers helped me out but I would have spent even less time if I had seen an example. Here I provide you one:

[image: Optional Azure Function Parameter example]